# android - custom function called before onCreateView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity and inside it a fragment, where i'm trying to display a gridview with pictures.

If I try to access the view in onCreateView() of the fragment, i do get a non-null handler and all is OK :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_pics_grid, container, false);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    return v;
```

However, since i need to get data from a DB first, so I access the gridview in a custom function :

```
public void loadData(Bar bar) {

    if (showBarDetails.getBar() != null) {

        bar = showBarDetails.getBar();
        GridView gridview = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        barImageArray = bar.getImages().toArray(new BarImage[bar.getImages().size()]);
        gridview.setAdapter(new PicsAdapter(showBarDetails, barImageArray));

    }
}
```

In the latter case, gridview is always null, which means this function is called before onCreateView - any ideas why is this happening ?

I initialize the Fragment in the activity's onCreate function as follows :

```
picsFragment = new PicsFragm(this);
```

Then I have an AsyncTask pulling data from the DB where I call :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<Bar> result) {

    if (result.getError() == null) {
        sbd.setBar(result.getResult());
        if (sbd.getPicsFragment().isResumed())
            sbd.getPicsFragment().loadData(sbd.getBar());
    } 
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since your custom function is called before the onCreateView, I would suggest initializing a global variable(s) in your custom function then calling the variable(s) in your onCreateView method.

```
//global variable declaration like a string or data source e.g
String myValue;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_pics_grid, container, false);
    //Get your global variable here
    String getValue = myValue;
    GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    return v;
}


public void loadData(String bar) {

    //initialize your global variable here
    myValue = bar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android documentation suggests that to communicate from an activity to a hosted fragment, the fragment can define a callback interface and require that the host activity implement it. The basic pattern involves implementing onAttach in your fragment, and casting the activity to a callback inteface.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Hi @jvra, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not help. What i'm doing currently is to call the task that fetches data from the DB (from the activity's onCreate). On the task's onPostExecute() method, it then tries to fill up the data fields in the fragment. Basically the application is trying to feed data into the fragment as soon as the activity has finished initializing. The problem is it seems the fragment is not fully initialized at that moment. Any further hints highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `ReentrantLock` to fix this. Create a variable in your fragment activity to hold the Database data:

```
private ReentrantLock dataLocker = new ReentrantLock();
private PicsAdapter adapter = null;
```

In `loadData(Bar bar)` rather than loading it directly into the grid view, load it into that variable:

```
if (showBarDetails.getBar() != null)
{
    bar = showBarDetails.getBar();
    barImageArray = bar.getImages().toArray(new BarImage[bar.getImages().size()]);
    dataLocker.lock();
    try
    {
        adapter = new PicsAdapter(showBarDetails, barImageArray);
        //Check if the grid view is made (this is run after inflation)
        GridView gridview = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        if (gridview != null)
        {
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        dataLocker.unlock();
    }
}
```

Then when you inflate your view, you make lock the dataLocker whilst you inflate. Once inflated, set the adapter if it already exists.

```
dataLocker.lock();
try
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_pics_grid, container, false);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    if (adapter != null)
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
finally
{
    dataLocker.unlock();
}
```

I'm not sure what thread you called `execute` on the `AsyncTask` on, so we use the `ReentrantLock` to make sure the threads aren't interfering with each other.